# Jquery - increment to next array on click with Json strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, click, increment

I have a simple question. Starting with Javascript/Jquery I wanted to create a simple way to review Chinese flashcards based on a simple increment on click to show the Chinese characters one by one with the definition.

Basically i would like to call the proper item in an Array one by one.

To do some testing, I succeeded in showing the next array on click but I can't find the solution to find the next Array.property the same way with a Json array.

Here is the code for what I already did which works fine but just for one straight Array (without Json - just to show you the result I'm waiting for):

```
<script src="./js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

        <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

          var arr = ["爱", "八", "爸爸", "杯子", "北京", "本", "不", "不客气", "菜", "茶", "吃", "出租车", "打电话", "大", "的", "点", "电脑", "电视", "电影", "东西", "都", "读", "对不起", "多", "多少", "儿子", "二", "饭馆", "飞机", "分钟", "高兴", "个", "工作", "狗", "汉语", "好", "喝", "和", "很", "回", "会", "火车站", "家", "叫", "今天", "九", "开", "看见", "块", "来", "老师", "了", "冷", "里", "零", "六", "妈妈", "吗", "买", "猫", "没", "没关系", "米饭", "明天", "名字", "哪", "哪儿", "那", "那儿", "呢", "能", "你", "年", "女儿", "朋友", "漂亮", "苹果", "七", "钱", "前面", "请", "去", "热", "人", "认识", "日", "三", "商店", "上午", "少", "谁", "什么", "十", "时候", "是", "书", "水", "睡觉", "说话", "四", "岁", "他", "她", "太", "天气", "听", "同学", "喂", "我", "我们", "五", "喜欢", "下", "下午", "下雨", "先生", "现在", "想", "小", "小姐", "些", "写", "谢谢", "星期", "学生", "学习", "学校", "一", "衣服", "医生", "医院", "椅子", "有", "月", "在", "再见", "怎么", "怎么样", "这", "这儿", "中国", "中午", "住", "桌子", "字", "昨天", "做"];
          var index = 0;
          $('#next').click(function(){ 
            $('#quote').html(arr[index]); 
            index = (index + 1) % arr.length ;
         });
        });

        </script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div id='quote'></div> <button id='next'>Next</button>

        </body>
        </html>
```

The result is fine but I would like to save time and retrieve the same data, incrementing on click the "next item" in the Json array which is like this :

```
var arr =
               [
                {
                    "Numéro": "1",
                    "Chinois": "爱",
                    "Pinyin": "ài",
                    "Français": "aimer, affection, apprécier",
                    "Classificateurs": ""
                },
                {
                    "Numéro": "2",
                    "Chinois": "八",
                    "Pinyin": "bā",
                    "Français": "huit, 8",
                    "Classificateurs": ""
                },
                {
                    "Numéro": "3",
                    "Chinois": "爸爸",
                    "Pinyin": "bà ba",
                    "Français": "père, papa",
                    "Classificateurs": "CL: 个,位[wèi]"
                },
                {
                    "Numéro": "4",
                    "Chinois": "杯子",
                    "Pinyin": "bēi zi",
                    "Français": "verre, coupe",
                    "Classificateurs": "CL:个,支[zhī],枝[zhī]"
                },
```

I would like to retrieve the same data as before. But I can't properly select just the strings with "Chinois". Then, I could  tweak the event and place it properly on a Webpage.

I hope I was clear enough.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following as the function handling the click event:

```
function(){ 
    $('#quote').html(arr[index].Chinois); 
    index = (index + 1) % arr.length ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew it was simple :)